# WP-CLI over SSH - wp command not found

Tags: wp-cli

I'm stuck trying to do the remote SSH with WP-CLI.

I have installed WP-CLI on my **Webfaction server** and tested it's working

```
# This is in server

$ wp --info

OS:     Linux web561.webfaction.com 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary:     /usr/local/bin/php56
PHP version:    5.6.40
php.ini used:   /usr/local/lib/php56/php.ini
```

But whenever I tried to do remote access (I'm on Windows10 using GitBash), I get this error:

```
# This is in my local comp

$ wp @staging --info

myaccount@web561.webfaction.com's password:
bash: wp: command not found
```

I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the @staging alias.

Path is definitely correct too because when I change it to non-existent directory, it gives `No such file or directory` error.

Have anyone experienced this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you access wp directly? `php /path/to/wp-cli.phar @staging --info`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I already set the PATH and can call `wp` within bash.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution here https://github.com/hrsetyono/wordpress/wiki/WP-CLI-on-Webfaction
.

This seems to be Webfaction specific issue

You simply need to open FTP and append this line in `/home/yourname/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be trivial, - but it was my solution. I simply hadn't installed WP-CLI on my machine. So I followed the install instructions here: [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) - and then it worked for me.